# Do I need to implement ServiceActivator in WildFly8 domain

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

My Wildfly 8 domain has two hosts Master and Slave. I need to start my application **only on one node at a time**. Do I need to implement `org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceActivator` for this?

I believe this `ServiceActivator` should be implemented in case of standalone servers only.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952769/clustered-singleton-using-wildfly

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Wildfly activates a MSC service, it notifies the class which implements ServiceActivator interface.

For your need (master/slave failover), singleton deployment (available wildfly 10 onwards) might be the right choice.

You can configure your MSC service as Singleton (across cluster) by using the SingletonPolicy.

Refer:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Singleton+deployments

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Singleton+MSC+services