# How can I cluster application-scope state in wildfly?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, infinispan, jcache, wildfly-cluster

I would like to cluster a map that is kept on application-level scope.

A first thought was to use a `@Singleton`, `@Clustered` bean with a field holding my data.
This does not seem to work and my guess is that it was [never implemented](http://wildfly-development.1055759.n5.nabble.com/Getting-on-the-same-page-with-Clustered-Singleton-td5056494.html)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27956003/1555615) proposes ways to implement clustered singletons but they seem complex.

The only alternative that I see, apart from manually updating db table(s), is to use a replicated cache.

**My question is:** Is it advised to declare and use an infinispan cache (like [this](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/277328?_sscc=t#thread-post-980667)) for solving this problem?
If yes, what settings should I use to avoid dirty reads?
Is there any other option to this relatively simple problem in the era of wildfly-18?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned a cluster, you need to use `standalone-full-ha.xml`

Edit the file and add the following configuration

```xml
<cache-container module="org.infinispan.extension" name="infinispan_container" default-cache="default">
    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
    <global-state/>
    <distributed-cache name="default"/>
    <local-cache name="localCache"/>
    <replicated-cache name="replicatedCache"/>
</cache-container>
```

You have different caches available for your application, if you wish use a replicated cache, you can inject it in your app with

```java
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/datagrid-infinispan/container/infinispan_container/cache/replicatedCache")
Cache cache;
```

Comment: " you need to use `standalone-full.xml`":  I guess you mean `standalone-ha.xml` or 
 `standalone-full-ha.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Diego's response assumes that you are using the WF modules distributed by Infinispan (note the datagrid-infinispan namespace).

To use an arbitrary Infinispan cache defined in WF's Infinispan subsystem, use jndi names of the form: `java:jboss/infinispan/cache/your-container-name/your-cache-name`.

e.g.

```java
@Resource(lookup="java:jboss/infinispan/cache/foo/bar")
private Cache<K, V> cache;
```

WF will manage the lifecycle of the cache, ensuring it is started/stopped when necessary.

Comment: Will this be automatically distributed across nodes of the cluster?

Comment: The behavior of the cache is based on its configuration, as defined in the infinispan subsystem.