# How to view the objects in wildfly ejb dist cache

Tags: ejb, wildfly, infinispan

We have WildFly full-ha profile with ejb dist cache in domain mode.
There is no SFSB in application.
But it looks like state transfer occurs on startup of nodes.
Is there any option view the objects in wildfly infinishapn ejb dist cache?

Comment: state transfer occurs on the startup of nodes. yes, it is the default behavior.

Comment: "Is there any option view the objects in wildfly infinishapn ejb dist cache". I didn't understand your question. could you please give some examples? Tks

Comment: Since there is no statefule session beans in the application, I wonder which objects are in ejb dist cache. Is there any way to inspect?

Comment: Yes. please check my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156357/how-can-i-cluster-application-scope-state-in-wildfly/59176149#59176149

Comment: Is it possible to view via JMX or something like that?

Comment: You can use JMX to see statistics, not cache values or keys.